Reed solomon with large integers
I'm implementing a Reed Solomon decoder in Python and I need to work with a list of integer numbers as big as:
431342463989546253785077373442290488783641371510581447158771232564590378566506202497840942203692125599102483668104985535184673222126688267451461551029552225120863879807700151666268097961736850113389185836025910736750088241471690221220380815545054191318352257376386927199075073712066726411311940926640390256563705687923971280428196795856610068683890362377414173559009566579510696600590413743016255872434879918446978346024125056474388799795616270980593397495444886904192948970915296369630549129898500220796950432514574871348504215207257457541776162250665624775531569639430755420743731445824259253623897302014173644584001238979539702407287392789350623901699991440954555018748814897774151918787353010783056750928376375868963622359439111912181527492684982711155758822266672767109404625858691155301236203564633378481454060988996286638882259638387453109906465055608773235933571370248051506765627953841471005240347278298790390168520961862377804180929592439109016208662423598558206310091405387286957714987756538471564458094147894745967636623037290109959447279012331473848414760440234296528113990145799913499612884532666181559451603203265822627825028619778109008056635913188828774400000000000000000000000000000000000000000000008593065383657945401827199314985016752557827063865127911092300571481094864342801874

when I execute decode I get: OverflowError: Python int too large to convert to C long
The numbers come from evaluating a polynomial, if I apply a modulus on the polynomial these numbers are smaller, but then the RS decoder doesn't work properly (I guess some properties are lost in the modulus operation) anyone has a workaround for this situation?
Thank you

Show us some code by hitting [edit]. What "decoder" would that be?

"too large" - the library is written in C and doesn't support Python's bignum. "Evaluating a polynomial" - assuming the polynomial is based on the actual data to be encoded, then a modulus should be applied, This is how the original RS version encoding works, and unlike the later and more common version where a fixed polynomial is used. The decoders for the original version are different than the BCH version. Link to Wiki article: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reed%E2%80%93Solomon_error_correction#Reed_Solomon_original_view_decoders .

@rcgldr sorry for the late reply, if I apply a modulus to the polynomial, would that affect the RS decoding capability?

@MaartenBodewes it's just a call for decode in the Python's reedsolo library, it gets as a parameter a list of integers corresponding with the polynomial coefficients

@AngelaBR - in order to use that library, you'll need to use the library to encode | evaluate data, in which case it will be able to decode the data encoded by the library. If you're using custom code to encode | evaluate data, you'll need custom code to decode it. The Wiki article explains how to encode and decode data, for both versions of Reed Solomon code (original and BCH versions). https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reed%E2%80%93Solomon_error_correction
